# Symlink when the directory already exists

Tags: centos, symlink

We have added an NFS share onto our web servers and need to set-up a symlink - however, we are not sure how to do this when the directory already exists.

```
Webserver directory : /home/example/public_html/images    
NFS target : /nfsshare
```

We want to have a symlink from /home/example/public_html/images -> /nfsshare

The NFS share has an up to date copy of everything in /home/example/public_html/images and we want it anytime someone goes to https://www.example.com/images/123.jpg or references /images/123.jpg in HTML that it shows the file /nfsshare/123.jpg for example

When we create the symlink

```
ln -s /nfsshare /home/example/public_html/images/
```

it appears to work fine but when we browse to /images it still shows the original content and the nfsshare folder is then inside the images folder

```
[root@host01 images]# ls
index.html  nfsshare  image.png
```

Is there any other way when you want to in effect point a folder to somewhere else rather than its current location?

Comment: This question might better be asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [UNIX & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a symlink is to create a "virtual" folder (or file) that points to an existing folder (or file).  But you can't create a folder or file when it already exists -- more precisely you can't create a "virtual" folder (symlink) when a physical directory already exists.

... and  if I understand you correctly, you already have an existing `/home/example/public_html/images` directory.  You can't have both; you'd need to remove (or rename) the existing web server directory.

As an aside, the symlink got created inside the folder because you specified an existing folder name as the target.

**Update:**
Assuming a sane set of permissions on the server, you probably need to do this as `root` or using `sudo`.  You should probably also verify that the permissions on the NFS folder restrict your web app(s) to read-only access.

Comment: OK so if rename the existing folder and then do the symlink using the above command it should work as expected?

Comment: Yes.  But I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.  If the folder already contains the images you want, why do you need the symlink?  Another concern would be if there's another process that's updating this folder ... with the symlink in place you might be overwriting files in `/nfsshare`, which I'm guessing you don't want.

Comment: At the moment we have a single web server with images locally - we are moving it to nfs so we can then share the images folder between 2 web servers but don't want to have to update any existing code to point images to a different directory name

Comment: In that case it does sound like the existing folder is superfluous, and you should be safe renaming.